# Using JQuery nested Accordion in sub elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not really familiar with jquery, please i have this html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<div id='accordion'>    
<h5> Header Title2</h5>
  <div id='term'>1st Term</div>
     <div id='payment'>
        Payment1 <br>
        Payment2 <br>
     </div>
<div id='term'>2st Term</div>
     <div id='payment'>
        Payment A <br>
        Payment B <br>
     </div>
</div>
```

I would want these in accordion form, with element in  being the header, and Terms, which will appear as submenu under  will also have payments under it when clicked... How do i handle this in jquery?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a vary basic accordion - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/93b9P/. Just make sure you as jQuery to your page.

Comment: @ TimSPQR that example is not a nested accordion...

Comment: Here is one - http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/